# php How to add comma's in an array without making it separate values?

Tags: php, string, replace, cpu-word

My string:

```
'KCP-PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country' //for example: 'KCP-PRO;Jon Doe;Box 564;02201;USA'
or
'KCP-SAT-PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country'
```

How can i change the first part (KCP-PRO or KCP-SAT-PRO) and change it to (KCP,PRO or KCP,SAT,PRO)? The outcome has to be:

```
'KCP,PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country'
or
'KCP,SAT,PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country'
```

Comment: Is this always the format of your string? You could just use a php built in function (str_replace out of the top of my head) to replace the '-' with a ','.

Comment: there could be a '-' in the address like 'streetname 1-3', so only the '-' in the first field should be replaced

Comment: It looks like the title for this question in not appropriate to the question

Comment: what title would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried the code myself but I guess this will do the trick

```
$string = 'KCP-SAT-PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country';

$stringExploded = explode(';', $string);
$stringExploded[0] = str_replace('-', ',', $stringExploded[0]);
$output = implode(';', $stringExploded);

//output should be KCP,SAT,PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: wouldn't that make the KCP, SAT and PRO seperated fields? Than you get: 
    KCP;SAT;PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country

Comment: The explode will make stringExploded an array of strings, with KCP-SAT-PRO one string in the first index of the array. Then as you can see, he replaces the '-' with ',' for the first index of the array I.E. KCP-SAT-PRO. Then he implodes the array again with ';', which means that he concatenates all fields while adding a ';' character between each pair of fields.

Comment: @ponciste Always explain what your code does, if OP knew that this existed he probably wouldn't have asked the question

Comment: @Glubus you're right! and thanks for your explaination! P.S: I've just tried the code myself on `phptester.com` and it worked fine.

Comment: I'll try it and when it works (or not) i will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @user269811 basically the `explode` function returns an array of elements splitted by a given character which in this case is `;`. Afterwards this statement `$stringExploded[0] = str_replace('-', ',', $stringExploded[0]);` will ONLY consider the first element of the array to replace the `-` with the `,` so the replacement will be affected only on this string `KCP-SAT-PRO` which is the first element of array determinated with `$stringExploded[0]`.

Comment: did you remove the comment or do I have allucinations? :D

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `preg_replace_callback` function with the following regex

```
^[^;]*
```

So your code looks like as

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/^[^;]*/",function($m){
     return str_replace("-",',',$m[0]);
},"KCP-SAT-PRO;first_name last_name;address;zipcode;country");
```